# Is there any way to restrict my public service or activity to a group of applications?

Tags: android, android-activity, service

We can make service accessible to other apps by keeping exported=true but then all application can use it. Is there any way that only my group of apps can access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following should work.

1. Create a permission with protectionLevel=signature
2. Declare  with the above permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding permissions that restricts use of your app by other applications. You can use that permission in your group of apps to access your service/activity.

Comment: permission with protectionLevel=signature should do the job.

Comment: Yes, if all your apps are signed with same certificate.